# retrieving doubles in NSMutableArray converted with [NSNumber numberWithDouble:doubleVar]

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, double

I am looking for what is probably a simple answer to my novice question.  I know that `NSMutableArray` can only hold objects, so when I put the double into the array I used the `[myArray  addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:aValue]];` conversion method.  What I need to do now is to pull the values out as doubles and average them.  I believe I will use the fast enumeration method vs. FoR looping.

I just need to know how to get the following to work.

```
double total;

total = [myArray objectAtIndex:i]
```

Answer (score 7):

```
total = [[myArray objectAtIndex:i] doubleValue];
```